# ecommerce:addItem is required to track ecommerce tracking

Tags: google-analytics

Is it required to add `ga('ecommerce:addItem'`, to track ecommerce tracking

```
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
  'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
  'name': 'Fluffy Pink Bunnies',    // Product name. Required.
  'sku': 'DD23444',                 // SKU/code.
  'price': '11.99',                 // Unit price.
  'quantity': '1'                   // Quantity.
});
```

Comment: Code formatting

Comment: Standard or enhanced ecommerce tracking?

Comment: Does the answer helped?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in order to add items to the shopping cart, you have to use the `ecommerce:addItem` command.

I would recommend using [Enhanced Ecommerce](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce) along with Google Tag Manager as a best practice.